# Google's FragmentTabsPager.java

Tags: android

I want to create a sample app using [Google's FragmentTabsPager.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html), but I can't find any XML of this code, 
Anyone knows what is the layout file of this [FragmentTabsPager.java?](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html). Or any guide to achieve my sample app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the layout of that code.

```
<TabHost 
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >

                <TabWidget 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="0"
                    />

                <FrameLayout 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
```

It works well.